# Python console application can't make a link using colorama

Tags: python, string, sockets, python-sockets, colorama

tools.py Linked function:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style
def Linked(url, text=None):
    if text is None:
        text = url
    print(f"{Fore.BLUE}{Style.BRIGHT}{text}{Style.RESET_ALL} ({Fore.BLUE}{url}{Style.RESET_ALL})")
```

Part of my client side code, that is responsible for making links:

```
import tools
import threading
import socket
from colorama import Fore, Style

def receive_messages(client_socket):
    print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
    while True:
        try:
            data = str(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
            if data.startswith("$"):
                try:
                    action = data.replace("$","").lower()
                    if action.startswith("link:"):
                        content = action.replace("link:","")
                        info = content.split("~", 1)
                        print(f"Link Text: {info[0]}, URL: {info[1]}")
                        tools.Linked(info[0], info[1])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error formatting received message, because {str(e)}")
            else:
                print(data)
        except:
            break

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(client,))
receive_thread.start()
```

I got a problem, when it checks if the message is starting with `$link:`, if it is, then it formats the text as a link.

It gets to the point where it check if message starts with $, else it prints raw message. So I think it doesn't detect $ at the start because it prints just text without links.

Thank you in advance.

I tried adding try-except blocks, error handling, printing out some info, but there was nothing useful. I expect making a blue clickable link with custom text.

Comment: If you receive the data and then print it, what is the second `recv` receiving?

Comment: @snakecharmerb The first one is receiving clients username, the second one is receiving messages that client sent

Comment: @snakecharmerb I think I already got the solution, I'll post it as answer, so other people may find this article useful. But the problem isn't solved, because after fixing the first one I got another problem.

Comment: Assuming TCP, it is not message-based, so any code that does `recv(1024).decode()` is probably broken.  TCP is a byte stream and needs a protocol and likely buffering to accumulate and extract complete messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution:

```
data = str(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
if "$link:" in data:
 try:
  index = data.find("$link:")
  data = data[index:]
  content = data.replace("$link:", "")
  info = content.split("~")
  tools.Linked(info[0], info[1])
 except Exception as e:
  print(f"Error formatting received message, because {str(e)}")
```

I think the issue was in all that startswith and indexes stuff, so I made the if statement way shorter. Now it seems to work